# how to work with rbegin() inside sort function?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort a string using sort function:
Heres is a string: Indexing start from **zero**

```
"effort"
```

my aim is to sort this from index **(1 to 4)[n=1,m=4]** in *Descending order* that is to produce a string:

```
"erofft"
```

I used function sort as:

```
sort( str.rbegin()+ (str.length()-1-m) , str.rbegin()+ (str.length()-1-n) );
```

but this doesn't seem to work: I guess I am having difficulty in understanding *rbegin()* iterator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use `begin()` (`+n` and `+m`) and a custom comparator?

Comment: @UnholySheep didn't get what you said

Comment: `sort` takes iterators as arguments but giving it reverse iterators will not make it go backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no point in using `rbegin` for this. All you need is a sort with a custom comparator:

```
std::sort(str.begin() + 1, str.begin() + 5, [](auto l, auto r) {
    using Trait = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(str)>::traits_type;
    return !Trait::lt(l, r) && !Trait::eq(l, r);
});
```

A little explanation of the above:

- for all ranges in the standard library the end is exclusive, so we need to sort in the `[1, 5)` range.
- `sort` has an overload that accept a custom comparator. This custom comparator decides between two elements who comes first. We use a lambda for this.
- to decides which element comes first, we could just do `l > r`, but that would not be the right way. A `std::basic_string` has a traits template argument which decides how strings are compared and sorted. It could have a custom trait that makes the string case insensitive. My version correctly uses that.

Comment: this is not giving the desired result, this prints eoffrt. Also, I am having difficulties in understanding the full syntax, I  am a beginner can you provide me a source with a brief explanation of this code.

Comment: @PushkarSoni fixed it. You need to go with the index up to `+ 5` because the range is exclusive on the end. Check it now.

Comment: ok, this works fine now, so sort function expects arguments as (start, end+1) am I correct?

Comment: @PushkarSoni if you define `end` as the last element you use then yes. But I strongly suggest to change your definition of `end` to "one past the last element". That's how all algorithms in the standard library operate.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that. end is one past the last element was the key.